# D3: Cannot read FRED URL

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to read an inflation time series from the following US Federal Reserve URL:

https://fred.stlouisfed.org/data/CPIAUCSL.csv

The first thing to note is that this URL is public and the data can be downloaded manually. I can also download it from the R command line very easily:

```
> url = 'https://fred.stlouisfed.org/data/CPIAUCSL.csv'
> dfr = read.csv(url_sl)
> head(dfr)
                DATE VALUE
1 1947-01-01 21.48
2 1947-02-01 21.62
3 1947-03-01 22.00
4 1947-04-01 22.00
5 1947-05-01 21.95
6 1947-06-01 22.08
```

However, when I try to read this URL from D3.js I get an error. Below I show the D3 code followed by the error message copied from my Chrome browser.

Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
    <script>
        //Program works if I read file from disk.
        //d3.csv('CPIAUCSL.csv', function(error, data) {
        d3.csv('https://fred.stlouisfed.org/data/CPIAUCSL.csv', function(error, data) {
            if (error) throw error;
            data.forEach(function(d) {
                console.log(d);
            });
        });
    </script>
</html>
```

Error message:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://fred.stlouisfed.org/data/CPIAUCSL.csv. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.
```

Later:

Upon reflection I suspect this is not a D3 problem but a Javascript problem,  or general web programming problem. Consequently, I am adding the tag Javascript to this question.

Comment: Simply download it to your server directory/computer folder and change the path. There are tons of docs about this error, here is a starting point: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy

Comment: I would like to load the data directly into the browser's memory, without going through a server or a secondary disk file.

It occurs to me that the line

 <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>

loads code into memory from a foreign URL without a lot of heavy lifting from the client side programmer. Isn't there some similar mechanism for placing data into the browser's memory?